# Django character latin1 mysql

Tags: django, character-encoding, latin1

I create a django application with existing MySQL database, the problem is the  encoding to database is  latin1_general_c and the utf8 characters is save like this `ñ => Ã±` ,  `ó => Ã³`, i need present the information in that page in correctly form but django show the information of database like this

```
recepciÃ³n, 4 oficinas, 2 baÃ±os

i need show like this

recepcíon, 4 oficinas, 2 baños
```

For many reasons I can't change the database to utf8

what do I do for show information  the correctly way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django seems to [explicitly require](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#encoding) that your database use UTF-8:

> Django assumes that all databases use UTF-8 encoding. Using other encodings may result in unexpected behavior.

That said, it should be possible to use the custom [`OPTIONS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-OPTIONS) setting to pass the desired character set to the database driver. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15654019/2395796), in which setting `charset` solved the problem. But you should check the documentation for the specific MySQL driver and database that you're using, since these options are not used by Django itself.

As suggested by the quote above, even if this works to correctly translate strings between the database and unicode, parts of Django still won't work correctly. For example, to correctly validate the length of a `CharField` Django has to know the encoding, and it will always assume `UTF-8`.

Comment: ohh very very thanks you saved my life, I use 'charset': 'latin1','use_unicode': False , no work 'use_unicode': True