# convert u"\xb8\xa3\xbd\xa8\xd2\xbb\xc7\xf8" to "\xb8\xa3\xbd\xa8\xd2\xbb\xc7\xf8"

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, character-encoding

MYSQL charset is UTF-8, but the data in it is GBK, and Django model reads GBK as unicode.

How can I get the right encoding?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read  [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: 1). You really need to mention which Python version you're using (preferably by using a tag), since Python 2 & Python 3 handle Unicode differently. 2). You _can_ do the conversion specified in your title using `u"\xb8\xa3\xbd\xa8\xd2\xbb\xc7\xf8".encode('latin1')`, but I suspect we need more info to answer your question properly. Eg, would you like your string to be converted to `u'\u798f\u5efa\u4e00\u533a'`?

Comment: My Python version is python2.7, and I use `u"\xb8\xa3\xbd\xa8\xd2\xbb\xc7\xf8".encode('latin1').decode('gbk')`, it works,thank you!

Comment: The sane solution is to translate your database from GBK to UTF-8 instead.

Comment: It is a legacy database, I can not change it.

Comment: Can you do `SET NAMES gbk` after connecting to MySQL?  That might be simpler than changing all the code.

Comment: Is this what you are expecting?  `福建一区`?

Comment: @RickJames yes,it is,How can I `SET NAMES gbk` in django?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523138/django-character-latin1-mysql and the links there.