# django - how save in mysql "Angela CR CÃ©spedes RodrÃ­guez" not "Angela CR Céspedes Rodríguez"

Tags: php, python, django, yii, django-rest-framework

I have to use the same database for two apps one with yii as backend php and other with django the problem that i have is when i save a name for example in yii "Angela CR CÃ©spedes RodrÃ­guez" vs in django "Angela CR Céspedes Rodríguez" i need save in django in the same way.

Comment: Starting with `s = u'Angela CR Céspedes Rodríguez'`, `print s.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')` outputs `'Angela CR CÃ©spedes RodrÃ­guez'`.  But why would you want this?

Comment: thanks i need this for compatibility with the old backend

Answer (score 1):

See Mojibake in [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'charset': 'utf8mb4',
                    'use_unicode': True, },
    },
}
my.cnf:

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
default-collation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523138/django-character-latin1-mysql